# Get latest duplicates based on a column sql powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a table retrived from a sql query like below

```
   Id   Date-Time            FilesA    FilesB

   556  2020-10-13 21:12:04  temp1.txt fels.csv
   133  2020-09-08 03:22:16  NA        temp2.txt
   556  2020-10-13 22:02:44  temp1.txt fels.csv
   203  2021-08-03 03:22:16  macs.xml  temp2.txt
```

I'm pulling out FilesA and FilesB column and doing some operation for all Ids of Id column. But there are some duplicates in the Id column, I need to perform the operations only on the latest Id based on the Date-Time column like for 556 I need to work with FilesA and FilesB of the 3rd row as it is generated latest i.e, on 22:02. I can have multiple duplicates of different Ids like this.  How do I achieve that with powershell script?
All I've found to identify duplicates is using csv which doesn't seem helpful here as I don't need csv and for the time date column is there anything like converting the retrieved column data to date time object and then compare? I'm lost.

```
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$Dataset = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
$SqlAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
$DataSet.Tables[0]
$data1=$DataSet.Tables[0]
$data1.FilesA #some operations
#need to perfrom the actions on all ids and for duplicates only on the latest ones
```

Comment: Have you considered modifying the SQL query to filter it down before it gets to Powershell? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` to group the rows by `Id`, then pick the one with the newest date from each group with `Sort-Object -Descending |Select -First`:

```
$newestRowPerId = $data1 |Group-Object Id |ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group |Sort-Object -Property 'Date-Time' -Descending |Select -First 1 
}
```